# Reading a local file, encoding to base64, I would like to give the user an option to save the result to file

Tags: javascript, file, download, savefiledialog

I have a webpage encoding a local file into Base64, and would like to give the user an option to save the result - now residing in a html element - without going back to the server.
I could post the data to a back-end webpage, save as file, and offer a <a href= .. but I would much appreciate the option of fulfilling this on the client side. The file can easily be too big for a post..
Could I write som javascript code to initiate a save dialog, and push the file content back to the user if he chooses to accept the file ?

thanks for any help !
Kind regards
Ketil Duna

Comment: I think this question is missing one half

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
var file = //your Base64 encoded file
var url = 'data:application/octet-stream;base64,' + file;
window.open(url);
```

You should adapt the code so the mime type matches the content you are serving (application/pdf...)

To pass a file name you will have to use a anchor tag like follows :

```
<a href="data:application/octet-stream;base64,/*YOUR FILE DATA*/" download="your filename">
```

but this is not crossbrowser.
See http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/08/Downloading-resources-in-HTML5-a-download

Comment: Thank You, I now get a downloadable file! Is there any way to specify the file name as well ?

Comment: The value of the `download` attribute is the file name.